# Why is npm deleting my npm folder when trying to install gulp?

Tags: node.js, apache, npm, gulp

I installed node into a "custom" directory:

```
 c:\Apache24\htdocs\node\
```

Everything is there.  When I run:

```
 $ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

like the [docs](https://gulpjs.org/getting-started) suggest it appears to install.  Then, if I attempt:

```
 $ npm init
```

it gives me the errors:

```
                Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.
                js'
                    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
                    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
                    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
                    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
                    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
                module.js:549
                    throw err;
                    ^

                Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.
                js'
                    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
                    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
                    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
                    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
                    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

When I investigate I find that the npm folder ("c:\apache24\htdocs\node\node_modules\npm") is completely gone - erased, no longer there!  This also happens to me when just attempting to install plain gulp and not the gulp-cli.  Does anyone know why this could be happening?

I'm running windows 8.1.

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have had issue with copy node module directory from one place to another to another before

What i did was

first of all
run `npm init`
and then `npm install --global gulp-cli`

that worked for me before

Comment: This works up to the point of installing the gulp, but the npm folder is still removed after I run "npm install --save-dev gulp", so I no longer have access to npm.

Comment: can you post the output of the package.json

Comment: I posted the package.json above.

Comment: This is my suggestion uninstall npm, restart the pc, install latest verion of npm in to your custom folder, and first run npm init before install any thing

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is exactly what I did for the current install.  I have no idea why it removed the folder.  I did, however, extract the folder from the node archive file and put it back in the directory and now npm is working.  Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Please don't accept the answer if it didn't really solve the issue but the follow-up comment did. It'll just confuse others who google here with the same problem. It's fine however to edit the question and reflect the correct information.

Comment: when you run the npm init it deletes every file in the node modules directory and also create a new package.json file